# Attempting to alter values in numpy array - TypeError: 'float' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am certain the answer is already in Stack Overflow but I cannot see it, probably as I do not understand the answer... if that makes sense. So, in layperson's terms. I am getting this error...

```
Attempting to alter values in numpy array
```

When I try to dynamically apply a threshold to a numpy array like this...

```
self.data = self.data[self.data < self.threshold] = np.nan
```

I am passing `0.1` as self.threshold

I will keep digging but if anyone can help I would appreciated it.

Comment: Why did you write `self.data =` in addition to `self.data[self.data < self.threshold] =`?

Comment: Yes. I have just seen that... as to why... I have no idea! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I will leave here in case anyone else has a moment of madness. The obvious issue is that I am trying to assign to itself rather than just altering in place.